# Spacing reset every time there is a new page

Tags: spacing, line-spacing

I am writing my math assignment in latex for the first time and I ran into a spacing error as all of the text on the next page is pushed to the very left, even though I want it to still be aligned with the text on the previous page. What should I do? I have highlighted the section where the new page occurs. (Note: Something similar happens between pages 2 and 3 as well)

View the file on overleaf: https://www.overleaf.com/read/bvmngfdsmcbz

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Without a short, yet complete code reproducing the problem, we can't do much.

Comment: @Bernard Sorry about that! I have now attached a link to view my overleaf file.

Comment: A link to an external source, even Overleaf, isn't permanent, so a small compilable example demonstrating the problem really is necessary within the question.  Otherwise this question won't be of any use to future viewers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your document class, `amsart`, defaults to a two-sided layout, suitable for printing. Pass `oneside` as a class option, i.e. use

```
\documentclass[12pt, reqno, oneside]{amsart}
```

That should fix it. Also see section 3.1 / page 9 of the amsart author's guide.

Comment: The `twoside` option is the usual cause for the different alignment of recto/verso pages.  Unfortunately, `amsart` (with which I happen to be well acquainted, having been a member of the AMS support team for many years) centers page content horizontally, whether right or lefthand page is involved.  So something else is going on.  (I don't have an overleaf account to check.)

Comment: The only strange thing the OP is doing is that all the text is basically into nested `enumerate` environments. He also calls `geometry` and `parskip`... I'm on a phone now so I can't run it...

Comment: @barbara beeton Ah, thank you, I wasn't aware of that. That said, I just tried, the uneven margins *do* in fact disappear if you pass `oneside` as a class option. As @Rmano points out, loading `geometry` may also have to do with it; commenting out that line also fixes the problem.

Comment: So it is possible that geometry defaults to two-sided document and inherits the main document options...

Comment: The reason for `amsart` centering, whether `oneside` or `twoside`, is that, in production, the output is set up for imaging on printing plates (16 up), not for a page-at-a-time laser printer.  So anything different is unexpected, caused by the user; the `geometry` package is *not* recommended, at least not for anything submitted to the AMS for publication.